# AWS S3 Bucket policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have created a bucket with cloudformation:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Parameters:
  BucketName:  
    Type: String
    Description: "Choose a name for the S3 Bucket"
    Default: "myrandomnameforbucket"
  S3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      AccessControl: "Private"
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
```

Now I'm writing a bucketPolicy but I'm facing some issues. What I want to achieve:

- USER A (UserA) can upload to S3
- USER A (UserA) can NOT DELETE from S3
- ALL users (in my environment, not public) can read from S3
- ALL users (in my environment, nob public) can delete from S3

How can I achieve this?
At the moment I denied a delete from userA and allowed an upload from userA.

```
          - Effect: Deny
            Principal:
              AWS: 
                !GetAtt UserA.Arn
            Action: "s3:DeleteObject"
            Resource: 
              Fn::Join:  ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "S3Bucket", "/*"]]
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: 
                !GetAtt UserA.Arn
            Action: "s3:PutObject"
            Resource: 
              Fn::Join:  ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "S3Bucket", "/*"]]
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "?" # * is public?
            Action: s3:GetObject
            Resource: 
              Fn::Join:  ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "S3Bucket", "/*"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand there are two questions:

1. how to grant access to all IAM users when excluding anonymous users
2. how to restrict one user more than the others, that is: removing rights you just granted to others

The first question sounds easy at first, as [the documentation states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html):

> In resource-based policies, use the Principal element to specify the accounts or users who are allowed to access the resource

So this would mean you could do something like:

```
Principal:
    AWS: !Ref "AWS::AccountId"
```

But when I tried it just didn't work. When setting the arn of a specific user it worked for me. This seems like a bug to me. Or an unclarity in the documentation. There is [this other report I found](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=838365&#838365).

Anyway, what you can do is to use `Principal: AWS: "*"` and then use a `Condition` to [restrict to IAM users only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#w278aac26c13c11c33b9b5c11).

The second question is much easier: policies are evaluated such that explicit `deny`s have priority over general `allow`s, [see documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow).

The resulting policy can be e.g. written like this:

```
S3Policy:
  Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
  Properties:
    Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Deny
          Action: "s3:DeleteObject"
          Resource: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "S3Bucket", "/*"]]
          Principal:
            AWS: !GetAtt UserA.Arn
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: "s3:PutObject"
          Resource: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "S3Bucket", "/*"]]
          Principal:
            AWS: !GetAtt UserA.Arn
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: ["s3:GetObject", "s3:DeleteObject"]
          Resource: !Join ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", Ref: "S3Bucket", "/*"]]
          Principal:
            AWS: "*"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              "aws:PrincipalType": ["User"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowGet",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/user1"},
        "Action": [
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyDeleteObject",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:user/user1"},
        "Action": "s3:Delete*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow anyone in your account to access bucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-number-without-hyphens:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:Put*",
            "s3:Delete*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name",
            "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Here is a template in JSON format I quickly put together. My assumption here is that your group "ALL users (in my environment, nob public)" is everybody in the account. Hence, we define it in the third block. You can always manipulate the principal with whatever you want.

If you have any question please ask, I am happy to help.

Comment: did you try that out? I have just worked on this for some time and apparently account based principals don't work in s3 policies. See also this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=838365&#838365

Comment: So do you want to go cross account? If not, you can just deny everything and just allow specific users or roles to perform certain actions. What is a group in your case?

Comment: this also doesn't work when using the same accounts account id. IMO the only way to go is to use an IAM policy and assign it to a group

Comment: Interesting. In that case I believe IAM is the only option. However, it sounds very weird that an explicit deny on the bucket is not working. I will need to experiment with that.

Comment: Looks like there is set of templates that may help you -> https://gist.github.com/actionjack/d900c6587297f24d83b14c2b7a85200f